# How can i get the number of members in a event on facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get the number of members who set the option "GOING", "MAYBE" and "INVITED".
There is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't expose a `count` method on these tables. The only way to do this is to make a query that returns all the members and count them with your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/v1.0/{event_id}/invited?summary=true&limit=0
// use "limit=0" if you're not interested in data, just the summary
```

which returns info, such as:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "maybe_count": 0, 
    "declined_count": 0, 
    "attending_count": 3, 
    "count": 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try and format your code correctly using the SO tools.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to process the information you have several ways to attack it

- graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/invited  - Returns all invited users and each one has an rsvp_status value that does not quite match up to the other options below (attending, unsure, declined, not_replied)
- graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/attending - exactly what you would expect
- graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/maybe - exactly what you would expect
- graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/noreply - exactly what you would expect
- graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/declined - exactly what you would expect